# R data frame to array string

Tags: r

im have data frame
df

```
col1|col2
---------
A   |1
B   |2
C   |3
```

How simple way to create string js array?

```
'[["A",1],["B",2],["C",3]]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `toJSON` from `jsonlite` after setting the column names of the 'data.frame' to NULL.

```
library(jsonlite)
toJSON(setNames(df1, NULL))
#[["A",1],["B",2],["C",3]]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"), 
 col2 = 1:3), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```